# Sum of Three Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having a bit of trouble with this problem and was wondering if I can get some advice. Here is the problem:

> Suppose $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n = A$, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n = B$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n = C$ are convergent series , where $A, B, C$ are constants. Evaluate $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n + b_n + c_{n + 1})$ if it exists.

So my attempt to this problem:

I know that the sum can be distributed inside the brackets, such that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n + b_n + c_{n + 1}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_{n + 1}
\end{align*}

We know that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n = A$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n = B$, so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_{n + 1} = A + B + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_{n + 1}
\end{align*}

I am not exactly sure how I am supposed to find $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_{n + 1}$. Would appreciate some tips and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simply:
$$
A+B+C-c_1
$$
The trick is just to realize than the C sum lacks the first term, which is $c_1$.

The sum is allowed to be performed because the series are convergent. If two of them diverges, the sum do not necessarily will diverge, which by the way, is not the case in here.